# EF Core Inserting new record - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am facing an exception while inserting new record into db with Entity Framework Core.
I have been struggling with this exception almost 2 days with no luck.

Here is the code:

```
if (orgUnits.OrganizationUnits != null)
        {
            foreach (OrgUnit unit in orgUnits.OrganizationUnits.ToList())
            {
                if (!groups.Any(x => x.OrgUnitPath == unit.OrgUnitPath))
                {
                    foreach (User user in fetchedUsers)
                    {
                        if (unit.OrgUnitPath == user.OrgUnitPath)
                        {
                            if (curUsers.Exists(x => x.googleId == user.Id))
                            {
                                curUser = _domainUserService.GetByEmail(user.PrimaryEmail);
                                newUnitUsers.Add(curUser);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var photoUrl = googleServices.GetUserPicture(directoryService, user.PrimaryEmail, company.companyId);
                                curUser = _domainUserService.Convert(user, company, defaultSignature, photoUrl);
                                curUser.isLocked = true;
                                
                                if (curUser != null)
                                {
                                    _context.Add(curUser);
                                    newUnitUsers.Add(curUser);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        curUser = new DomainUser();
                    }
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    var defaultCompanyProfile = company.companyProfiles.First();
                    var newDomainGroup = new DomainGroup()
                    {
                        Name = unit.Name,
                        assignedProfile = defaultCompanyProfile,
                        Company = company,
                        assignedSignature = defaultSignature,
                        Etag = unit.ETag,
                        OrgUnitId = unit.OrgUnitId,
                        OrgUnitPath = unit.OrgUnitPath,
                        ParentOrgUnitId = unit.ParentOrgUnitId,
                        ParentOrgUnitPath = unit.ParentOrgUnitPath,
                        Users = newUnitUsers,
                        isCustom = false
                        

                    };

                     domainGroupsNEW.Add(newDomainGroup);
                    _context.Add(newDomainGroup); <---- Here is where the error is occurs
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    newUnitUsers = new List<DomainUser>();

                }
            }

      
        }
```

Entity Class:

```
   public class DomainGroup
{
   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<DomainUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public virtual Signature assignedSignature { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyProfile assignedProfile { get; set; }
    public string OrgUnitPath { get; set; }
    public string OrgUnitId { get; set; }
    public string ParentOrgUnitId { get; set; }
    public string ParentOrgUnitPath { get; set; }
    public string Etag { get; set; }
    public bool isCustom { get; set; }
    public virtual DomainGroup parentGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
 System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.TryGetEntry(Object entity, IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, ISet`1 handledForeignKeys, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.FireStateChanged(EntityState oldState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func`3 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState entityState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at PanelServices.SyncService.OrgUnitsSync(String customerId, String adminEmail, Company company)
```

I have also tried to insert the records using AddRange() but it did not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, best regards.

Comment: maybe an id (or a contraint preventing) is not assigned yet on the newDomainGroup object? like a property there is not complete and null? You must go over all the properties in that object are actually correctly set.

Comment: Please check if you have inner exception in main exception. Maybe it will be more verbose.

Comment: Either your entity doesn't declare a key or it is misconfigured.

Comment: Consider sharing your entity class here as well?

Comment: @MattB I have shared entity class.

Comment: @AluanHaddad there is a key in the entity class.

Comment: @Hostel I have double checked it and there is no inner exception.

Comment: @JohanHerstad everything looks correctly settled.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `[Key]` attribute to the `Id` property or setting using the fluent API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=fluent-api

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell yes i've tried both.

Comment: @darkfolcer, after adding [Key] attribute to the Id property did you do add-migration and update-database? (followed by building the project again)

Comment: @noobprogrammer yes i did. but no luck

Comment: Your entity has a lot of navigation properties. (Going to assume those classes all have Id properties.)You could try commenting out the navigation properties out one by one and doing migrations to establish if one of them is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @darkfolcer The error says you have Id value as null but still can you can put a debug point and check exactly what's going on?

Comment: Try to use SQL Server Management Studio to check the table definition, whether the Id column is auto generated and whether it is null able. Besides, before calling the SaveChange method, you could add a debugger to check the entity property value,  whether the entity contains a null value (especially the key value and foreign key). If it contains the null value, try to set a value for it.